# Can't print string extract from images using both pyocr and pytesseract

Tags: python, string, unicode, ocr, unicode-string

I want to extract the Thai text from images using PyOCR but I can't print the string.

Here's the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image
import sys
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders

tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
if len(tools) == 0:
    print("No OCR tool found")
    sys.exit(1)
print("Will use tool '%s'" % (tool.get_name()))

langs = tool.get_available_languages()
print("Available languages: %s" % ", ".join(langs))
lang = langs[3]
print("Will use lang '%s'" % (lang))

txt = tool.image_to_string(
    Image.open('test2.png'),
    lang=lang,
    builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
)

print(txt)
```

And it gives me this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tess.py", line 29, in
>   
>       print(txt)   File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in
>   position 0-2: character maps to

Here's the code form pytesseract which gives the same error.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test2.png'), lang='tha')
print(text)
```

After I tried encoding it with utf-8. It gives me this output.

> b'\xe0\xb8\x99\xe0\xb8\xb2\xe0\xb8\xa2
>   \xe0\xb8\xa0\xe0\xb8\x84\xe0\xb8\x9e\xe0\xb8\x87\xe0\xb8\xa9\xe0\xb9\x8c
>   \xe0\xb8\xaa\xe0\xb8\xad\xe0\xb8\x99\xe0\xb9\x80\xe0\xb8\xad\xe0\xb8\x81'

Here's the images that I use.

[image: Some Thai name]

Comment: Have you tried writing to a file instead of printing? Some terminals/shells can't display all unicode characters.

Comment: That works after I encoded the file with utf-8 and write to file in bytes, but it leads to the same problem if I tried to read from from the file which give me this error.
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 49: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to `print` this data, rather than just store it? Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I need to fill some PDF forms with the data so I think it would be easier to work with the PDF if I know that the data that I'm using is correct. And I'm using python 3.4.4.

Comment: It seems that I could still write the data to the PDF correctly even if I can't print it out in python. So thanks anyway.